# IF(SUMPRODUCT(MAX formula using R

Tags: r, if-statement, excel-formula, max, sumproduct

I have the below table in R and wish to produce an additional column which, in Excel, would be performed using the formula:

=IF(B2=0,SUMPRODUCT(MAX(($A$2:$A$11=A2)*($C$2:$C$11=C2)*($B$2:$B$11))),B2)

This formula says:
If Unit price = 0, then:
return the maximum Unit price of all other sales to
that same customer and
of the same item.

If unit price does not equal zero, then return same Unit price.

The desired output, with respect to columns A:C is:

- Unit Price 2
- 2
- 5
- 1
- 2
- 4
- 5
- 2
- 3
- 7
- 6

```
structure(list(customer = c("John", "Atticus", "Sally", "Bridget", 
"John", "Atticus", "Bridget", "Atticus", "Crystal", "Henry"), 
    `unit price` = c(2, 0, 1, 0, 4, 5, 2, 3, 7, 6), item = c("x", 
    "x", "y", "y", "y", "x", "y", "x", "x", "x")), class = c("spec_tbl_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -10L), spec = structure(list(
    cols = list(customer = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), `unit price` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), item = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector"))), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
    "collector")), skip = 1), class = "col_spec"))

# A tibble: 10 x 3
   customer `unit price` item 
   <chr>           <dbl> <chr>
 1 John                2 x    
 2 Atticus             0 x    
 3 Sally               1 y    
 4 Bridget             0 y    
 5 John                4 y    
 6 Atticus             5 x    
 7 Bridget             2 y    
 8 Atticus             3 x    
 9 Crystal             7 x    
10 Henry               6 x
```

Comment: Please provide usable data (and not assume a transcription service).

Comment: Please add data using `dput` or something that we can copy and use. Also show expected output for the data shared. Read about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Comment: I apologize for the poorly written question. I edited it to include reproducible data and desired output. Hopefully this is the correct format. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `group_by` to consider the calculation on a per-customer basis, then `mutate` to add the column:

```
library(dplyr)
DF %>% 
  group_by(customer) %>%
  mutate(unit_price2 = if_else(`unit price` == 0, max(`unit price`), `unit price`))
```